# vimで意図しない文字列についたハイライトを消したい

Tags: vim

以下のように日本語やjsonの一部で不要なハイライトがついてしまいます。
おそらくプラグインやデフォルトのシンタックスの設定が悪さをしていると思うので、
ひとつずつプラグインを外したりしながら調査すれば原因がわかりそうな気がしていますが、
もし何か良い解決策があれば教えてください。

- vimrc
  https://github.com/tackeyy/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc
- plugins
  https://github.com/tackeyy/dotfiles/blob/master/.dein.toml#L68

[image: https://gyazo.com/97de316d8c7a93268f6260d79e276e2d]

[image: https://gyazo.com/c335482f9ded8625b2016780af291026]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

詳しく見てませんが、スペルチェックが原因じゃないですか？

```
59  set spell                                   " スペルチェック
```

`spelllang`に`cjk`を設定すればスペルチェックを使いつつ日本語を対象から外せます。

```
set spelllang+=cjk
```

あとはまぁ何かしら`spellfile`を設定して１つ１つ単語をファイルに放り込んでやるとか。
私の場合は基本スペルチェックがうっとおしいんで、markdownやmbox、txtのファイルタイプにしか使ってません。

Comment: set spellを外してみたところハイライトされなくなりましたので、set spellが原因だったようです。

Comment: あとはmarkdownやmbox、txtのファイルタイプにだけスペルチェックを使うなどアドバイスをいただいた方法を試してみます。

Answer (score 1):

```
:echo synIDattr(synID(line("."), col("."), 1), "name")
```

を実行すると、カーソル位置のsyntax要素の名前が表示されますので、それを元にシンタックスファイルをgrepすると手がかりがつかめるかもしれません。
（このコマンドについては `:help synID()` を参照。）

Comment: ありがとうございます。  日本語の上にカーソルを置いて上記のコマンドを実行したのですが、コマンドの結果は空でした・・